# pass data from the server side to the GAS client side

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a function for a web app that makes copies of templates, as parameters it receives the name of the template and the id of the template.

**CODE.gs**

function generate_(idTemplate, name) {

```
 var template = DriveApp.getFileById(idTemplate);
 var folder = 'folder id';

var copyName = name + "-" + CurrentDate;// the date on which it was created is added
  var copy;
  try {
    copy = template.makeCopy(copyName, folder);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.stack);
  }
var nameF = copy.getName();
var linkF = copy.getUrl()
Logger.log(nameF,linkF)
  return getFile(nameF,linkF) //these values are the ones i want passed to the client side.
}
```

This function is the one that im using to  pass the copy name and url to the client side. I understand that in js to return multiple parameters you have to do it through an array.

```
function getFile(nameF,linkF){
var array = [nameF,linkF];
return array;
}
```

This is the client-side script I use to try to retrieve that generated copy data:

**HTML**

```
<script>
        function getValues(){
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(copyValues).getFile();
        }
        function copyValues(values){
         
          var nameF = values[0];
          var urlF = values[1];
        console.log(values);
         console.log(nameF);
          console.log(urlF);
          console.log("values were passed successfully,");
        }
    </script>
```

I am using a button to test if it is passed correctly, however I am unable to display this data, the browser console shows me null on the logs.

what I could be doing wrong? , i already tried  `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(copyValues).getFile(nameF,linkF);` in the client side
but did not work.

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="create(); getValues();"
```

this is the button, it triggers both `create()`,the script that creates the copies and `getValues();` the script that gets the name and url of that copy. the template copies are created successfully but the file name and url are not retrived to the client side.

Comment: In the client `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(copyValues).getFile()` passes no parameters.  In the server "Code.gs" `getFile(nameF,linkF)` is expecting 2 parameters so `nameF` and `linkF` are undefined.  I don't know how `generate_(idTemplate, name)` is executed but that is what creates the template file.  I think what you need to do is store the file information array in [Property Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties?hl=en) and then use a different function  with `google.script.run` to retrieve it.

Comment: @TheWizEd many thanks , so in summary is not possible to call google.script.run if the function that i want to retrieve the values is expecting parameters? i tried `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(copyValues).getFile(nameF,linkF)` but still could not pass the values to the client side, however your answer worked perfectly .

Comment: No, you can pass parameters but in your case what are `nameF` and `linkF` in your client script?  And if you alread know `nameF` and `linkF` why pass it to the server only to be immediately returned to the client?

Comment: @TheWizEd  `nameF`  and `linkF` are the new name and the url of the generated copy of the template, im pasing these values to the client, in order to pop up a hiperlink to that copy.

Comment: `generate_` is on the server (Code.gs) as are the variables `nameF` & `linkF`.  The values are passed to `getFile` and returned in an array.  Now on the client side your call to `getFile` has no parameters so nothing to return.  Even if you tried `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(copyValues).getFile(nameF,linkF);` `linkF` and `nameF` are undefined on the client side so you would be passing undefined.  Variables on the server side are not persistent, which means they go away when the function returns.  You would need to store them somewhere such as Property Service to retrieve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to get the file info.

As shown in the following screenshot, when I click the button the name and url are shown in the input field.

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function showTest() {
  setFileInfo();
  let html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("HTML_Test");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,"Test");
}

function setFileInfo() {
  let id = "1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxE";
  let name = "Copy of Template";
  let template = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  let copy = template.makeCopy(name);

  let properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  let property = [copy.getName(),copy.getUrl()];
  properties.setProperty("FileInfo",JSON.stringify(property));
}

function getFileInfo() {
  let properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  let property = properties.getProperty("FileInfo");
  if( property ) {
    return JSON.parse(property);
  }
  return "Error";
}
```

**HTML_Test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="getFileInfoButton" type="button" onclick="getFileInfoClicked()" value="Get File Info"><br>
    <input id="getFileInfoText" type="text">
    <script>
      function getFileInfoClicked() {
        try {
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( 
            function (value) {
              document.getElementById("getFileInfoText").value = value;
            }
          ).getFileInfo();
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

GS:

```
function launchmydialog() {
  let t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("ah2");
  t.t1 = "one";
  t.t2 = "two";
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(t.evaluate(),"Dialog");
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txt1" name="text1" value="<?= t1 ?>" /><br>
    <input type="text" id="txt2" name="text2" value="<?= t2 ?>" /><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Dialog:

[image]